# delete specific messages from kafka topic __consumer_offsets

Tags: apache-kafka

I want to delete all messages that are contained in the `__consumer_offsets` table that start with a given key (resetting one particular consumer group without affecting the rest).

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kafka comes with a ConsumerGroupCommand tool. You cand find some information in the Kafka [documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#basic_ops_consumer_group).

If you plan to reset a particular Consumer Group ("myConsumerGroup") without affecting the rest you can use

```sh
> bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --reset-offsets --group myConsumerGroup --topic topic1 --to-latest
```

Depending on your requirement you can reset the offsets for each partition of the topic with that tool. The help function or documentation explain the options.